# Alljoyn ios sample for Onboarding issue

Tags: alljoyn

I was able to run the ios sample of onboarding but I am facing two issues 1. when the onboarding sample runs I am presented with this error "ER_BUS_INVALID_AUTH_MECHANISM" please see attached image also and after that when the bus is connected and I try to configure the Home wifi I am presented with this error "ER_BUS_SECURITY_NOT_ENABLED",please see attached image also.

[image: Sample code onboarding]

[image: sample code onboarding1]

Comment: please provide 1) which Alljoyn version you're using 2) which authentication mechanism you're using when creating the bus attachment

Comment: thanks for your reply @Lino I am using the alljoyn version of 14.12 in the ios app and in the think client the version 14.12. The auth mechanism that I am using is "ALLJOYN_SRP_KEYX ALLJOYN_ECDHE_PSK".